# Error while trying to use Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0

Tags: c#, ado.net, oledbconnection

I am trying to read data from an Excel .xlsx spreadsheet and put it into a datagridview.
However when ever I run my code it gives me the following error:
 `System.InvalidOperationException: 'The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.'`

After some googling it looks like its something to do with the version of excel i have installed (I have Office 2019 Pro installed on my machine) but I dont really know how to rectify it. I have tried changing the version number to various things on the "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" bit of my code but with no success. Im not 100% sure how this works, is it my version of Excel installed on my machine that matters or is it some kind of library I should have that I need to get within visual studio?

My code is as follows:

```
DataTable rs = new DataTable();

using (var odConnection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data source=c:\myfile.xlsx;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;';"))
            {
                odConnection.Open();

                using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = odConnection;
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]";
                    using (OleDbDataAdapter oleda = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd))
                    {
                        oleda.Fill(rs);
                        dataGridView4.DataSource = rs;
                        dataGridView4.Font = new Font("MS Sans Serif", 8);
                    }
                }
                odConnection.Close();
           }
```

Comment: This blog article contains a pretty exaustive list of the causes for this error: https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/280/solved-the-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-mach

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/cannot-use-odbc-or-oledb#resolution which states: _The Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 Redistributable is not provided as a recommended solution for the indicated scenarios as both the Access Database Engine 2016 and M365 Apps use the same major version identifier (16.0) which may introduce unexpected behaviors..._ [Microsoft Access 2013 Runtime](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39358)

Comment: You may also try NuGet package: `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access`

Answer (score 0):

The last time I battled with this issue my problem was 32 bit/64 bit, I think you should check that first. Also read the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/troubleshoot/winautomation/support-tips/databases/ace-oledb-12-0-provider-not-registered-on-local-machine)

Comment: Thank you for the reply
Sorry if this is a silly question but i am still learning:
Is it a case of the c# programming being in (for example) 32 bit and the version of excel in 64?
If so how do i tell which version both is in?
Also if that is the issue is there a way of changing the c# project from 32bit to 64bit (or visa versa)?

Comment: Running those installs from that link you gave me worked!
However it leads onto another question - do i now need to run those programs on every machine i install the programme on? If so is there any way to automate this installation?

Comment: @Yippiekaiaii you can change the target CPU in the project properties page (right click on your project name in solution explorer and select properties, scroll to target platform and change it to the version that matches the version of excel you are using).

Comment: About your second question, I think that will depend on the Microsoft Office installation package used on the machine in the first place. I encountered only one case where I had to install Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable, only one